# php opening link duplicate content

Tags: php, url, blogs

So on my blog page I am using substr to display only a bit of the articles. The idea is once someone clicks one of the headings they will be sent to a page displaying the full article.

When i click the link i get the right heading in the url for example i click the 4th blog entry i will be redirected to index.php?id=4.The problem is that on this page the content remains the same, nothing changes. How do I get it so when i click the article I will be directed to a page containing only that article in full and no others. Thanks in advance guys this has been wrecking my head all day.

```
<?php
$dbinfo = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
$result = mysql_query($dbinfo) or die(mysql_error());
$return = '<p><a href="index.php"> Go Back To Content Page</a></p>';


if(mysql_num_rows($result) !=0):
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<div id="roundedbox"><h2><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['blog_id'] . '">' .  $row['title'] . ' </a></h2>';
    echo '<div id="date"><h5><p>' . $row['date'] . '</p></h5></div>';
    echo substr('<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>',0, 90)." .... "." read more</div>";

}
else:
    echo '<p> UH OOH! THERE IS NO SUCH PAGE IT DOES\'T EXIST </p>'; 
    echo $return;
    endif;  
?>
```

Comment: This is much easier to do if you have separate PHP scripts for displaying the overview vs. individual articles.

Comment: any ideas why its doing this though?

Answer (score 0):

The query you have in your code will return all the records for the table, what you want is the query to return the record based on the id parameter from the $_GET['id']. It's a good idea to make sure you're only using integers to prevent sql injection.

From your code you need to have a separate query to fetch the appropriate record using the $_GET['id'] parameter as follows...

```
    //the parameter is set and it is an integer
        if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_int($_GET['id'])) {
            $blogId = (int)$_GET['id'];
            $query = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content WHERE blog_id='$blogId'";
            // run query and get record data and output it

        } else {
            //code to return all records as list
            $dbinfo = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
            $result = mysql_query($dbinfo) or die(mysql_error());
            $return = '<p><a href="index.php"> Go Back To Content Page</a></p>';


           if(mysql_num_rows($result) !=0):
           while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
           echo '<div id="roundedbox"><h2><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['blog_id'].$row['title'] . ' </a></h2>';
           echo '<div id="date"><h5><p>' . $row['date'] . '</p></h5></div>';
           echo substr('<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>',0, 90)." .... "." read more</div>";

           }
           else:
             echo '<p> UH OOH! THERE IS NO SUCH PAGE IT DOES\'T EXIST </p>'; 
             echo $return;
           endif; 
          }
```

Comment: so do i keep my previous code and add this to my index page where i am displaying the data? im a little bit confused now

Comment: I've plugged in your code where it needs to go. It will help you if you test with a var_dump to make sure you're hitting the right loop.

Comment: im getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')' on the very first line. im adding this by using include dont think that should cause any problems...?

Comment: Include will not cause any problems, a good approx would be to set up your code using pseudo code and replacing with valid code as you go. This way it will be easier for you to understand the programme logic. I've updated the answer re the error